# Splitting into array based on two delimiters

Tags: python, split

I just want to be able to split both a `+` and `-` into a single array.

```
array = []
function = x+y-z
array = function.split("+")
array = function.split("-")
```

Expected output:

```
[x, y, z]
```

Obviously this isn't correct but can someone provide a real example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use module `re`:

```
>>>import re
>>>re.split(r'[+-]', 'x+y-z')
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for the split:

```
import re

function = 'x+y-z'
array = re.split("\+|\-", function)
print array # prints ['x', 'y', 'z']
```